# How to access Azure Maps API from browser using Azure App Service Active Directory authentication?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal.js, azure-appservice, azure-maps

I have an Azure App Service with Azure Active Directory Authentication enabled. So the users have been authenticated by AD. How do I use that authentication to call Azure Maps from the JavaScript in the browser?

I was able to make calls from the browser to the maps API using the maps shared key, but I obviously don't want to do that. I was also able to have the browser call my server, and have my server use the shared key to call the maps API, but I don't want my server to have to be the middle-man for every call.

Comment: You mean you want the user to login the app with azure ad auth, meanwhile, he will be able to call the azure maps api?

Comment: Basically yes. The user has already logged into AD and the site. I believe I should somehow be able to use that existing authentication to make the Azure Maps API calls from JavaScript.

Comment: A bunch of documentation on this and links to samples can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-manage-authentication

Comment: I've gone through all of that many times and still have not been able to get it to work in this specific scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your case, you can hit `https://webappname.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` to get the token to call Azure Maps API, please follow the steps below.

**1**.Navigate to the [resource explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) -> find your app service-> add `["resource=https://atlas.microsoft.com"]` to `additionalLoginParams` like below -> `PUT`.

[image]

**2**.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `App registrations`  -> find the AD App corresponding your app service -> `API permissions` -> add the permission `user_impersonation` of `Azure Maps` like below.

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you could not find `Azure Maps` on the first page, just go to `APIs my organization uses` and search for `ba1ea022-5807-41d5-bbeb-292c7e1cf5f6`, then click it and add the permission above.

[image]

**3**.Then when the user login the web app, after he consents the permissions,  you can get the token with endpoint `https://webappname.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me`, and use the token to call the Azure Maps API with javascript, in this way, the user just needs to login for one time, the token was generated via the azure ad auth.

**Note:** Before you getting the token, make sure the user logged in the app is already added as a role e.g.  `Azure Maps Data Contributor` in the Azure Map Account -> `Access Control (IAM)`, if not, follow this link to add it.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so very much, Joy Wang!